# Django - How to process GET with a url: with varying parameters such as ?derivate=22&engine=73?start_date=2017-03-05?end_date=2017-05-05

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

So I need to process a url which can be like this:

`/api/timelinedata/merge/?derivate=22&engine=73?start_date=2017-03-05?end_date=2017-05-05`

or it could just have start and end dates:

`/api/timelinedata/merge/?start_date=2017-03-05?end_date=2017-05-05`

Comment: Every `GET` parameter you want is inside the `request` object. So, inside your `views` you get `request.GET['parameter_name_here'].

Comment: @nik_m, why doesn't this work, what am I missing `@list_route(permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny], url_path='merge/(?P<example>[^/]+)$')
    def merge(self, request):`so

Comment: @nik_m I can't get the method to accept the request

Comment: Have you declare the methods? Like this: `@list_route(permission_classes=[...], url_path='...`, methods=['get', 'post'])

Comment: @nik_m I included the methods=['get'] and still get `Not Found: /api/timelinedata/merge/sdsdssdd/      "GET /api/timelinedata/merge/sdsdssdd/ HTTP/1.1" 404 55550`

Comment: You must provide more of your code. `urls.py`, `views.py`, the version of django-rest-framewok

Answer (score 0):

In your function you can access these values via `request` (or `self.request`):

```
do_something_with(request.query_params.get("derivate", DEFAULT_DERIVATE)
```